# Android ListView добавление картинок

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin

Не знаком с технологией xml, пытаюсь сделать "шаблон ячейки" для listView по [примеру](https://habrahabr.ru/post/301128/) , но приложение падает при запуске на Android [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С MainActivity проблем нет, это выяснил экспериментальным путем со стандартными `textViewResourceId` вроде `Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1`

Моя конечная цель достаточно простая, в ячейке - картинка по середине

**rowlayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/icon"
      android:layout_width="22px"
      android:layout_height="22px"
      android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
      android:layout_marginRight="10px"
      android:layout_marginTop="4px"
      android:src="@drawable/devushka" >
  </ImageView>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/label"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@+id/label"
      android:textSize="20px">
  </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System;
using Android.Media;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestChart
{
    [Activity(Label = "TestChart", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                "Linux", "OS/2" };


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            ListView listViewSlotMachine = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listViewSlotMachine);

            var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Resource.Layout.rowlayout, values);

            // присваиваем адаптер списку
            listViewSlotMachine.Adapter = adapter;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

На моей памяти ArrayAdapter (тем более с целевым классом string) является примером реализации "элементарного" списка. Следовательно Вам необходимо объявить не LinearLayout с вложенными объектами, а напрямую TextView. И получите свой список.

То, что Вам необходимо - это BaseAdapter.
Он более гибок с содержанию.
Ваш пример с картинкой [тут](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/adapters/create_a_custom_adapter_for_contacts/).

Можете доделать данный [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/746229/267201), дописав ImageView в "public override View GetView", если испытываете проблемы в XML (тут только C# код)