# Как программно добавлять элементы в xamarin android?

Tags: android, c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Как программно добавлять textView в ListView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using Object = Java.Lang.Object;

namespace TestAndoid
{
    [Activity(Label = "TestAndoid", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : ListActivity
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Sample text list 
        /// </summary>
        private string[] _myList = {"SampleA", "SampleB"};

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            var adapter = new MyListViewAdapter(this, _myList);
            ListAdapter = adapter;

            ListView.TextFilterEnabled = true;
            ListView.ItemClick += ListViewOnItemClick;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// On click
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="itemClickEventArgs"></param>
        private void ListViewOnItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs itemClickEventArgs)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Application, ((TextView) itemClickEventArgs.View).Text, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Custom adapter
    /// </summary>
    public class MyListViewAdapter : BaseAdapter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Context
        /// </summary>
        private readonly Activity _context;

        /// <summary>
        /// Items
        /// </summary>
        private readonly string[] _items;

        /// <summary>
        /// Custom constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <param name="items"></param>
        public MyListViewAdapter(Activity context, string[] items)
        {
            _context = context;
            _items = items;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets item
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="position"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override Object GetItem(int position)
        {
            return _items[position];
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns item ID
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="position"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns View for cells
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="position"></param>
        /// <param name="convertView"></param>
        /// <param name="parent"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var tView = new TextView(_context)
            {
                TextSize = 20,
                Text = _items[position]
            };

            return tView;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Count of items
        /// </summary>
        public override int Count => _items.Length;
    }

}
```